# How to pass variable from one activity to another?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stcq6.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OubmC.png)

I wanna make "btn_34" in [image2] to move "game39" class if user clicked "btn_21_2" in [image1]. If user didn't click "btn_21_2", Wanna make "btn_34" to move "game30". Which thing should I add or change in these pic?

Comment: When you want to pass values between activities use....startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode) ..... and then override onActivityResult function to get that value comes back from the second activity.....value passed through the intent using intent.putExtra(key,value) function.....please check this link for more elaboration https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: Java <> Javascript!

Comment: @paulsm4 I wrote the whole code on my answer, but app is still crashing. Can you help me?

Comment: @feisalramar I wrote the whole code on my answer, but app is still crashing. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post code and not images of code.

3 options: Quick, Standard, Best.

1-> Place `public static boolean button21Flag = false;` in your `game17.class` and when they click button `btn_21_2` change it to `true`. When you get to `btn_34`.

```
    if(game17.button21Flag)
        intent = new Intent(game26.class,game39.class)
    else
        intent = new Intent(game26.class,game30.class)
```

2 -> Place an Extra into the Intent when `btn_21_2` is clicked. And keep passing it, until you need it in `btn_34`.

```
btn_21_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view){
           Intent intent = new Intent(game17.class,game18.class);
           intent.putExtra("button21Flag", true);
           startActivity(intent);
      }
});
// in btn_34 getIntent.getBooleanExtra("button21Flag", false);
```

3-> This solution is based on how complex and convoluted your code will get, if you keep approaching it this way.

Create a singleton called GameState and have it keep track of the game state. Anything you would like to keep track of should go in here and when you get to the point where you need it you can access it anywhere via a static context.

(EDIT) To respond to your answer.

```
 public static boolean game17Flag = false;
 btn_21_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                game17Flag = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(game17.this, game18.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
//Remove this completely
{
    if (btn_21_2.isPressed()) {
        game17Flag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. More question... If I use option #1, Which row will be best to place it? & #2, How do I put in btn_34?

Comment: Hey, @avalerio! Umm... I wrote my whole code on answer. Can you help me?

Comment: @Jun I've updated my answer, and some friendly advice you seem to be going way to deep into Android develop without understanding basic java, a crash course in java could really help you in solving problems.